# A verbal offer followed by a rejection letter

Tags: hiring-process, job-offer

I recently received a phone call from the Head of School that my interview was successful. However, after one week's silence, I received a rejection letter from the HR system saying that my job application was unsuccessful.

I am wondering whether there are some changes in the final decision making? Or any other problems with the recruitment system? Shall I ask the HoS or HR? Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking it's the written letter that is the final answer, however you should contact them and clear it up.

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54666/i-received-both-an-offer-letter-and-a-rejection-letter-which-should-i-believe

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it may be nothing you did, it could be the funding for the position was removed.  But when you have contradictory information, it is best to clear it up with a call.

Answer (score 9):

The only way to find out what happened is to contact them and ask. Perhaps they found a candidate they liked better. OTOH, maybe this is some sort of mistake on the HR department's part.

The Head of School is probably the best place to start. He or she would know if this was a change of heart on their part, or if it is an error.

Answer (score -4):

You've got it in writing, John.  You're DONE.  Don't put any more effort into "why".  You can use that same energy and put it into securing an opportunity more fitting for you.

Comment: When faced with contradictory information it's always best to get someone on the phone to clarify.  Sometimes mistakes are made and the only way to know for sure is to ask.