# I received an automated email stating my application would not be considered, after my third interview

Tags: hiring-process, hiring

I recently applied for a job at a company.

I applied online on the company website at first, and since I did not have faith in the applicant tracking system, I got a referral(after a week). I wrote directly to the HR manager, following which I had three rounds of interview. After the third round of interview, I got an automated response that my resume is not going to be considered for further stages.

I'm confused. Have I got a rejection letter after my interview, or was this an automated email after my applying on the website?

Comment: Follow Joe's advice.  This may have proven your point about the system being unreliable, or they may have deleted you from the system because you've bypassed it.  They probably didn't consider the possibility when it was programmed.

Comment: If it was a automated letter it could be someone incorrectly used the application that you are entered in. Calling for clarifications is always wise but note they do not have to explain anything to you if you were rejected.

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54666/i-received-both-an-offer-letter-and-a-rejection-letter-which-should-i-believe/

Answer (score 14):

Could be any of those, hard to tell. But since you are clearly able to get in direct contact with the company, why not call them up to explain your doubts and ask for clarification? If they already rejected your application, this cannot hurt, and if you are still in the process and this was a mistake, it can only be beneficial to you.

Comment: Thanks. Have written to the HR directly. Will probably hear back by monday! fingers crossed!