# Application process stated not selected,but recieved a call for a interview

Tags: interviewing, human-resources

I recently applied for this huge company about two months ago and was just curious to know is their hiring process normal. Everyday I would check my status of the application and nothing will change. One particular day my status was not selected. Therefor I thought I didn't get the job. But two weeks later I received a phone call stating that I have a interview with the HR. IS this normal? Do HR really update the statuses online, because now I am confused??!

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54666/i-received-both-an-offer-letter-and-a-rejection-letter-which-should-i-believe

Comment: I dont think there is any standard by which HR departments and software applications work.  Be happy you got the interview and good luck!

Comment: What do you mean with "my status was not selected"

Comment: What did they say when you asked them about it? What info are you thinking random internet people might have about this un-named company's internal processes?

Comment: I don't think I did good with the interview. I check my status everyday. Well today it stated that I was not selected again. Should I be concerned or is it another clinch in the system?

Comment: I am confused too, why are you asking strangers instead of ...you know, asking them directly?

Comment: I wanted to know if anyone has gone through the same thing. This is a website were you are able to ask questions about different interviewing experiences right?

Comment: @Meagan You should go with what the real person said in the e-mail, but if you'd like, ask that person to clarify your concern, e.g. "I accept the offer to attend the interview on ....(date and time)... P.S. I noticed your application Web site still says 'not selected' for me. Is that normal?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is normal is that systems are often out of sync, data gets updated or not, processes fail.

If you have an interview, go to the interview and ignore what the web page status says.  What matters is what people say, not a web site status.  No matter what the web site says, you don't have the job until you've been offered the job and given a starting date.

Here are some things to explain the mismatch: someone was supposed to update the status, and they updated the wrong one; they updated it incorrectly; they're on vacation and didn't make the changes; something else that it is not possible to know.  It doesn't matter how big or small the company is.  A level of disorganization is completely normal, and it is sometimes visible and sometimes not.

It also doesn't do any good to try to figure out why it doesn't match.  You were offered an interview, so go to the interview.  It's probably not even worth bringing up the mismatch in the interview, because it really doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't think I did good with the interview. I check my status everyday. Well today it stated that I was not selected again. Should I be concerned or is it another clinch in the system?

Comment: You can't know.  Your best bet is to move on.  If you get a call then you can be pleasantly surprised.  If you don't get a call - well, you had already moved on.  Otherwise, you're just stressing yourself and it doesn't actually help.  Even better, go read AskAManager.org so the next interview goes better.

Comment: @Meagan Based on your comments, you should probably stop checking the application Web site. You already interviewed; now you must wait for their reply and/or follow the suggestions in [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p). As always, pursue other offers in the meantime. Don't wait for one company/job offer in your job search.

Answer (score 3):

Big companies often have hiring managers operate pretty independently from the HR team, and the systems they use aren't always well integrated.  It's entirely possible that one hiring manager saw your application and wasn't interested, so your status updated, then another saw it and was interested and therefore you get scheduled for an interview.  Don't overthink it. :)

Comment: I don't think I did good with the interview. I check my status everyday. Well today it stated that I was not selected again. Should I be concerned or is it another clinch in the system?

Comment: No way to know.  Assume you didn't get it, practice your interview skills and move on to the next company.