# negotiated job offer and am I being ghosted now?

Tags: salary, human-resources, negotiation, offer

I was offered a job and I negotiated the terms of the base salary last Monday. I have sent an email on Friday and called this Tuesday for an update.

Unfortunately, I have not heard back from the HR. Im in this waiting period of not hearing back from them and it is driving me crazy. If they wanted to rescind the offer, shouldn’t they have already? Or is this their way of ghosting me?

I interviewed with the company for six weeks so I’m just in shock if they are going to ignore me like this after negotiating. Please help and looking for advice and everyone else’s experience in situations like this. Thank you and I appreciate it.

Comment: What did they tell you at the end of the negotiations on Monday regarding next steps and timelines?

Comment: they said that they would speak to leadership about the counteroffer. She ideally wanted to get the deal done before labor day weekend. but I know leadership is very difficult to get in contact with because they are really busy (hence why my interview process took 6 weeks total)

Comment: What advice are you expecting? Just keep job hunting until you've a countersigned contract, nothing has changed.

Comment: Companies sometimes move at a glacial pace, as witness my experience (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54666/i-received-both-an-offer-letter-and-a-rejection-letter-which-should-i-believe). If you have a signed contract and a start date, it's pretty safe to assume you have a job. If you don't have both but have an offer, you *probably* have a job, but it's a good idea to keep looking; it would be rude for them to change their mind after making an offer but not illegal or un-heard-of.

Comment: Companies especially move at a glacial pace when a) senior leadership needs to be involved b) it's getting approval for something that they don't really want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You have mentioned that it took six weeks to  finish the interview because the leadership is so busy.

It seems reasonable to expect the process of counter offer to take weeks as well.  It is also possible that they don't like you offer and have decided to go with someone else.  Either way, there is nothing you can do to speed up the process.

I would suggest that you keep trying to contact HR, but don't pester them. Once a week seems reasonable to me.  In the mean time, keep looking for other jobs.

Comment: I'd also suggest that OP continues job-searching in case they actually ghost them or finish the negotiations.

Comment: If the HR point of contact got fired, then OP can just slip through the cracks (anecdotal). Lots of things can happen before the contract is signed.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate thing to do right now is a lost art in these days of text messages and email.

**Pick up your telephone**, and call the hiring manager or human resources.  Inform them that you're concerned about having received no information on the offer, and that you'll have to move on with your life if the company isn't going to produce a written offer soon.  When you have this conversation, be sure to ask that the company commit to a **specific date**.  This doesn't have to be a long, drawn out conversation.  It's absolutely best to do this by phone because you can get right to the point.

Until you receive a written offer letter, keep interviewing.  It's best to keep working toward a few backup opportunities rather than wait forever for this one that may not materialize.  It's perfectly fine to let the others know you're accepting a different offer *if* it comes to fruition -- they'll have to deal with it, just the same as if one of your prospects might decide that you're not the right fit.  Just don't hold up your life and livelihood for anyone's empty promises.

Comment: Absolutely. If you want an answer in realtime, you can't beat the phone.