# Double applied with a recruiter, recruiter said I was rejected but company contacted me for interview. What should I do?

Tags: recruitment, applications

A recruiter submitted me for a position that I applied to a month ago that I forgot about.

The recruiter later discovered the double-submission and told me that the company will not be considering me because of it.

Today, I received a call from the company to schedule an interview which I accepted.

Should I contact the recruiter to let them know? If so, would that jeopardize my chances if they reach out to the company?

I never signed any formal contracts with the recruiter, however I did send an email confirmation to accept them in representing me for this role.

Edit: I am in Canada if that matters.

Comment: If the company wants to talk to you, talk to the company. Tracking whether they got your name from a recruiter and whether they owe a finders fee is between them and the recruiter, Not Your Problem.

Comment: "Should I contact the recruiter to let them know?" Absolutely not!

Comment: You are not under any restrictions when it comes to the recruiter only the company using the recruiter to find you. This is why using a recruiter doesn’t benefit you as an employee.

Comment: Also if you do get a job from that company, be careful what you write on your public LinkedIn profile, that may open a can of worms.

Comment: Some companies will truly pass over a candidate in this situation, to avoid the potential for the recruiter making a claim for a finder's fee they don't want to pay. Others might just cut out the recruiter silently, or even openly if they can prove they'd already been in contact with you. But if the company regularly uses recruiters, that finder's fee shouldn't be an issue for them and (as noted already) if they are willing to burn a recruiter, they're likely willing to burn an employee too.

Comment: Unclear:  did you apply directly the first time?  Then via the recruiter the second time?  Or via the (same) recruiter twice?   If you went directly to the company, then the recruiter is telling you they won't consider you *via the recruiter* - as the recruiter unlikely doesn't know about the first submission.

Comment: We've had questions like this before, and in general IIRC the answer is that any relationship/agreement between the company and the recruiter is their business, not yours. Unless of course you signed something saying otherwise?

Comment: See also https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54666/i-received-both-an-offer-letter-and-a-rejection-letter-which-should-i-believe

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you applied on your own before the recruiter submitted, you are just fine.  You don't need to inform the recruiter.

What the recruiter is really saying, is that the company will not be considering you as part of their referral, but that is their problem, not yours.

The company is clearly considering you, since they invited you for an interview.  Go ahead with the interview and good luck.

Comment: IOW the recruiter lied.

Comment: @user207421 not necessarily. They discovered the same person had applied directly and through a recruiter, obviously they want to go direct as that saves paying the recruiters fee. So, they would tell the recruiter that they aren't proceeding. In this case the recruiter could simply have confused a message of "we aren't continuing this application" as they aren't interested in the applicant at all.

Comment: Alternatively the company has a policy of rejecting submissions from that particular recruiter without even reading them (I've been a part of that scenario in the past, on both sides of the recruitment fence) - they may not even know about the OP's double application in that case.

Comment: Would the recuiter have a claim on the commission if OP proceeded with the company directly and they found out later?

Comment: @levantpied - that is between the company and the recruiter, and this is one reason companies keep records of when applications were submitted. If the OP submitted their own application before the recruiter, well, the recruiter is out of luck.